# mysqli fetch rows shorter

Tags: php, mysqli

So I was making a script for a friend. using mysqli.
I wanted to know if there is a way you can order the script to fetch it in one go instead of doing it all induvidually. Is there a way to fetch it all like in Mysql?

code:

```
 if(isset($_GET['event']) && isset($_GET['unique_id']) && isset($_GET['local_id'])&& isset($_GET['username'])) {
      $unique_id=$_GET["unique_id"];
         $local_id=$_GET["local_id"];
         $username=$_GET["username"];

      $db_handle = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "pass", "oasisdata") or die("|-1");
      if($db_handle)
        if($_GET['event'] == 1)
        {
          $sql_result = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Bank FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db_handle));
          $result = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_result);

          if(!isSet($result)) {
             mysqli_query($db_handle, "INSERT INTO playerdata (Unique_Id,Username,Gold, Bank, Troop) VALUES($unique_id, '$username', 5000, 5000, 4)");
            echo "1|$unique_id|$local_id|5000|5000|4|0|86|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|";
        }else{
          $fetch = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Gold FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch);
          $fetch1 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Bank FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch1);
          $fetch2 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Troop FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch2);
          $fetch3 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Head FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch3);
          $fetch4 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Body FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch4);
          $fetch5 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Gloves FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch5);
          $fetch6 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Foot FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch6);
          $fetch7 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT CombatLog FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row7 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch7);
          $fetch8 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Item0 FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row8 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch8);
          $fetch9 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Item1 FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch9);
          $fetch10 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Item2 FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row10 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch10);
          $fetch11 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Item3 FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row11 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch11);
          $fetch12 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT CoordinateX FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row12 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch12);
          $fetch13= mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT CoordinateY FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row13 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch13);
          $fetch14 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT CoordinateZ FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row14 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch14);
          $fetch15 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Horse FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row15 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch15);
          $fetch16 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Hp FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row16 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch16);
          $fetch17 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT New FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'" ); 
          $row17 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch16);
          echo "1|$unique_id|$local_id|$row[Gold]|$row1[Bank]|$row2[Troop]|$row3[Head]|$row4[Body]|$row5[Gloves]|$row6[Foot]|$row7[CombatLog]|$row8[Item0]|$row9[Item1]|$row10[Item2]|$row11[Item3]|$row12[CoordinateX]|$row13[CoordinateY]|$row14[CoordinateZ]|$row15[Horse]|$row16[Hp]|$row17[New]|"; 
         }
```

if there are any errors too. please say so.
Thanks.

Comment: Just do it the same as mysql.  With the exception of `$db_handle` it is identical!

Answer (score 2):

This is basic SQL. Just select all of those columns in one query by separating them with commas `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table`.

```
$query = "SELECT 
    Gold, Bank, Troop, Head, Body, Gloves, Foot, 
    CombatLog, Item0, Item1, Item2, Item3, CoordinateX, 
    CoordinateY, CoordinateZ ,Horse, Hp, New 
FROM playerdata 
WHERE Unique_Id = '$unique_id'"
$fetch = mysqli_query($db_handle, $query); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch);
echo $row['Gold'];// outputs value of GOLD column
```

FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174). You need to either sanitize and escape your user input or use prepared statements.